# Error con cURL en PHP

Tags: php, curl

estoy haciendo el trabajo de final de grado y estoy teniendo un problema con cURL.

El trabajo es una tienda online, y cuando se confirma el pago debo acceder a una URL de una API local para actualizar el carrito, en este caso debe eliminarme el elemento del carrito.

La URL tiene 3 parámetros get que son "action", "id" y "cantidad".

El parámetro "action" indica que acción debe realizar la API.

El caso es que cuando accedo a esa URL con cURL no me da ningún error, simplemente me devuelve el status code 400 y no me elimina el articulo del carrito, pero si yo accedo manualmente a la URL de la API, me devuelve el status code 200 y me elimina el elemento del carrito.

Imprimo por pantalla la URL a la que acceder cURL y está correcta.

Este es el código donde utilizo cURL.

```
$url='http://localhost/tiendadiscos/api/api-carrito.php?action=remove&id='.$item['id'].'&cantidad='.$item['cantidad'];
                
                echo $url.'<br>';
                
                $ch= curl_init();
                
                curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
                curl_exec($ch);
                
                if(curl_errno($ch)){
                    echo curl_errno($ch).'<br>';
                }
                
                curl_close($ch);
```

Como digo, la URL que me imprime es la correcta, accede correctamente a la API, pero por algún motivo no me realiza la acción.

Este es el fragmento de código de la API donde se encuentra el error.

```
            $items = json_decode($this->getValue(), 1);

            for($i=0; $i<sizeof($items); $i++){
                
                if($items[$i]['id'] == $id){
                    $items[$i]['cantidad']-=$canti;
                    if($items[$i]['cantidad'] == 0){
                        unset($items[$i]);
                        $items = array_values($items);
                    }
                    $this->setValue(json_encode($items));
                    
                    return true;
                }
            }
            
            return false;
```

Siendo $id el parámetro de la URL id y siendo $canti el parámetro de la URL cantidad.

La API funciona correctamente cuando la utilizo en JavaScript y cuando accedo directamente a la URL desde el navegador, por eso creo que el problema está en cURL.

echo curl_errno($ch) no imprime ningún error, adicional a ello, los valores de $item['id'] y $item['cantidad'] van a ser siempre correctos puesto que provienen de la base de datos.

El status code 400 o status code 200 que imprime, es el resultado de la llamada al API, cuando accedo desde JavaScript o desde el navegador, me devuelve el status code 200, es únicamente desde cURL que me devuelve el status code 400 utilizando literalmente la misma URL.

Agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: has probado a usar: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.curl-error.php y ver que mensaje de error te da? quizas es mas descriptivo que el curl_errno y te da mejor idea de que problema es

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar a la pregunta qué imprime la URL que falla? Por otra parte, tu principal problema aquí es lo que yo llamo *programación optimista* o *programación ingenua*. No veo ningún esfuerzo por controlar errores. Tanto si cURL falla, como si los datos que quieres pasar a cURL son erróneos, lo propio es crear una respuesta con una clave `error` y manejar esa situación. Deberías pensar seriamente en una política de manejo de errores, es fundamental, en cualquier programa serio, más aún si se trata de manejar respuestas de API. Así, en la respuestas, verificas si hay o no una clave `error`